# Getting a lot of `circular dependency between chunks` warnings from Vite.js after using a index.ts barrel file for each component folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

After reading https://github.com/alan2207/bulletproof-react/blob/master/docs/project-structure.md. I've started to reorganize the folder structure for my react site that uses code-splitting. The component folders look like this:

```
src
  client
    product
       product-list
         index.ts
         product-list.tsx
         product-list-item.tsx
```

The index.ts is a barrel file that reexports the ProductList component

```
// product-list/index.ts
export { ProductList } from './product-list';
export type { ProductListProps } from './product-list';
```

But I'm getting many warnings like this from Vite during the build process:

```
Export "ProductList" of module "src/client/product/product-list/product-list.tsx" was
reexported through module "src/client/product/product-list/index.ts" while both 
modules are dependencies of each other and will end up in different chunks by current 
Rollup settings. This scenario is not well supported at the moment as it will produce 
a circular dependency between chunks and will likely lead to broken execution order. 
Either change the import in "src/client/product/product-list/product-list.tsx" to 
point directly to the exporting module or reconfigure "output.manualChunks" to ensure 
these modules end up in the same chunk.
```

Do I need to worry about this? Should I follow Vite.js suggestion to get rid of the index.ts file and just point directly to `product/product-list/product-list.tsx`?